# Change name of the last column in df stored in a list

Tags: r, for-loop, rename

I have a list with 5 data.frames. Now I want to change the name of the last column of each data.frame.
And I don't know exactly how many columns are in the df.

Example-data:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

df1 <- tail(mtcars)
df2 <- mtcars[1:5, 2:10]
df3 <- mtcars
df4 <- head(mtcars)
list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

Doing it one by one, this would be the command:

```
colnames(list$df1)[length(list$df1)] <- "rank"
```

Within a for loop, I would think that the command would then be:

```
for (i in seq_along(list)) {
  colnames(i)[length(i)] <- "rank"
}
```

But here I get the error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = `*vtmp*`) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? Maybe by the map-command?
Here I don't know how to include the index/length(df) to assign the colnames-command to the last column of the dataframe.

Thank you for your help :)
Kathrin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `last_col()` from dplyr within `map`:

```
library(tidyverse)

list <- map(list,~{
  
  .x %>% 
    rename(rank = last_col())
  
})
```